# Filtering an Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following index method

```
def index
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
    @search = @user.collections.where(status: params[:status]).search(params[:q])
    @search.sorts = 'created_at desc' if @search.sorts.empty?  
    @collections = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

I can then use the following links to display different indexes with that one action

```
<%= link_to "Collection", user_collections_path(current_user, :status => "Got") %>

<%= link_to "Wantlist", user_collections_path(current_user, :status => "Want") %>
```

But I want to also be able to link things like this, using other fields to filter the index

```
<%= link_to "Assembled", user_collections_path(current_user, :progress => "Assembled") %>
```

and I can't see how to write that. Should I be using scopes or should I have alternative methods in my controller? Is my initial "where" filter a bad way of doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found to do this is with the [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem.

Installed that. Named scopes in my model as follows

```
scope :assembled, -> { where(progress: 'Assembled') }
scope :got, -> { where(status: 'Got') }
scope :want, -> { where(status: 'Want') }
```

Added the has_scope fields to the controller

```
has_scope :got, :type => :boolean
has_scope :want, :type => :boolean
has_scope :assembled, :type => :boolean
```

Then my index method as follows

```
def index
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
    @search = apply_scopes(@user.collections).search(params[:q])
    @search.sorts = 'created_at desc' if @search.sorts.empty?  
    @collections = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Then I can link to the index with any combination of those scopes like this

```
<%= link_to collection, user_collections_path(@user, got: true) %>

<%= link_to assembled, user_collections_path(@user, got: true, assembled: true) %>
```

No routes and no extra methods. Very clean and expandable.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a Gem instead**

This is a solved problem. I would use a gem like [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) to do this rather than re-inventing the wheel. It has great helper methods to provide any kind of filtering that you would need.

Comment: I am using ransack for other things in my app and didn't realise it had this functionality. It's pretty brief on documentation. I'll try and find how ransack can do this.

Comment: I think I'm going with the has_scope gem for this. Don't see that ransack does exactly what I want on its own. May be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

Further to `San`'s answer, you'll need to create `routes` to handle any data you wish to send to your `index` (for filtering):

You'd do something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, except: :show do
   collection do
      get "(:query)", action: :index #-> domain.com/users/:query
   end
end
```

This will allow you to create links like this:

```
<%= link_to "Link", users_path(current_user, query: "whatever") %>
```

--

**Controller**

Inside your controller, all the links will hit your `index` action, so you'll just need some conditions to make sure you can handle a "non search" request:

```
def index
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])

    if params[:status].present? && params[:q].present?
        @search = @user.collections.where(status: params[:status]).search(params[:q])
        @search.sorts = 'created_at desc' if @search.sorts.empty?  
        @collections = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

Comment: Question, my Index method above is in my collections_controller not my users_controller. Should I then be writing a route for :collections rather than users as your routes code doesn't mention Collections?

Comment: I think I've found a way of doing this without adding a lot of routes. The has_scope gem seems to do exactly what I want with existing routes and plays nicely with ransack.